# How to highlight a node In extJs 4.1 tree panel

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.1

I have a ExtJs 4.1 tree panel. The tree is having multiple nodes. Now I allow user to perform contains search on tree node. So if I run the search on word `ASP.NET`, the search should highlight all the nodes who's text contains key word `ASP.NET`

How Can I do this?

Thank you

Comment: did you find my answer helpful, or does it not suit your needs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to search for children from the `TreePanel`'s root node, then use RegEx to test the value of the Node vs your search text.

**Working Example**

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
    root: {
    expanded: true,
    children: [
        { text: "Javascript", leaf: true },
        { text: "ASP.net", leaf: true },
        { text: "Also ASP.net", leaf: true }
    ]
    }
});

Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
    title: 'Example Tree',
    width: 200,
    height: 150,
    store: store,
    rootVisible: false,
    multiSelect: true,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    dockedItems: [{
    xtype: 'toolbar',
    dock : 'bottom',
    items : [{
        text: 'Search for ASP.net',
        handler: function(){
            var me = this,
                panel = me.up('panel'),
                rn    = panel.getRootNode(),
                regex = new RegExp("ASP.net");

            rn.findChildBy(function(child){
                var text = child.data.text;
                if(regex.test(text) === true){
                    panel.getSelectionModel().select(child, true);
                }
            });
        }
    }]
    }]
});
```

**Working jsFiddle** : http://jsfiddle.net/tdaXs/

**TIP:** Take note of the second parameter in the `.select()` method of the `TreePanel`'s `selectionModel`. This is the optional `keepExisting` parameter, which must be set to `true` when manually selecting nodes. See the docs: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.0/#!/api/Ext.selection.Model-method-select

Hope this helps!